# How to center word document in QAxWidget on first show

Tags: pyqt5, qaxwidget

I have prepared this example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import (QApplication, QMainWindow)
from PyQt5              import uic
from PyQt5.QAxContainer import QAxWidget



class MainForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)
    
        uic.loadUi(r"scroll_bar_test.ui", self)

        self.axWidget = QAxWidget('Microsoft Web Browser')

         path = 'C:/Users/Egon/Documents/FotoViewer/scroll_bar_test.docx'
    
         self.axWidget.setControl(path)
         self.setCentralWidget(self.axWidget)
    
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you start the program it will show a word document but the left side is hidden:
[image]

if i use the arrow keys to the right i see the whole document:
[image]

and from there on it is centered fine. My Question is how can the word document can be shown centered right at the start?

[image]
after using QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.axWidget.updateGeometry)

Meanwhile i found out that these lines center the document:

```
        self.setCentralWidget(self.axWidget)
        QTimer.singleShot(5, lambda: self.axWidget.setControl(path))
        QTimer.singleShot(5, self.axWidget.updateGeometry)
```

The time for the Qtimer has to be the same in both shots. Both has to be done with a timer otherwise it doesnt work. Unfurtunately the user sees first a very narrow document like the last foto and then a flash and then the right presented document.
Additionaly this doesnt happen on other computer. I have tryed with 3 other people and they didnt have this problmem.

Comment: Just to be sure, does the problem still happen even if you remove `loadUi`?

Comment: Hi, yes it also happens without loadUi. I have a other example from github, there is no using of loadUi and it is even worse, only a corner of word document is visible. Excel and Powerpoint is shown correct, only word makes this trouble.

Comment: If you resize the window after it's appeared (and before interacting with the ax control), does the problem fix or does it still have the wrong size?

Comment: after resizing, for instance maximizing the main window and resize it back, it shows correctly.

Comment: Please be more precise with your testing and their description: does it show correctly only after maximizing ***and*** restoring, or is it correct right after maximizing? And what after basic resizing (through the window borders)?

Comment: after maximizing and restoring it shows correct. Precise: run programm it shows wrong, hit maximize it shows correct, restore it shows correct. If i only stretch right or left side it stays wrong although the text is moving.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Windows machine, so I can't test, but I'd suggest trying one of these: 1. use a QWidget container with a basic QVBoxLayout, set that widget as central widget and add the QAxWidget to the layout; 2. delay `setControl()` with a basic `QTimer.singleShot()` (test with different timeouts, including 0); 3. delay a `updateGeometry` with a QTimer: `QTimer.singleShot(100, self.axWidget.updateGeometry)` (again, test with different timeouts); both 2 and 3 could be done in the `resizeEvent()` override with a basic flag (defaults to `False`) to check that it's done just once.

Comment: I tryed a lot of combination. Only  QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.axWidget.updateGeometry) has an unwanted effect at all. I attached a foto of the result.